# Constructor with same name, but different signatures does not run

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I have those 2 constructors:

```
public StockItem(Long id, String name, String desc, double price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
    this.price = price;
}

public StockItem(Long id, String name, String desc, double price, int quantity) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

Doing this in another class:

```
StockItem item2 = new StockItem();
item2.setId(Long.parseLong(idField.getText()));
item2.setName(nameField.getText());
item2.setDescription(descField.getText());
item2.setPrice((double) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText()) * 10) / 10);
item2.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantityField.getText()));
System.out.println(item2);
```

The output is:

```
id, name, desc, price
```

Why does it not take the quantity into the item2???
If I do:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(quantityField.getText()));
```

It DOES give me the quantity.

Could anyone tell me why it does not realize to use the second StockItem constructor. Tried it even after deleteing the first StockItem constructor.

Comment: You don't even *call* the constructor, you call a setter. Is your setter broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `toString()` method in the `StockItem` you have to include the `quantity` as well. For example:

```
public String toString() {
    return id + ", " + name + ", " + description + ", " + price + ", " + quantity;
}
```

This way when you do `System.out.println(item2);`, the `toString()` will be invoked with the `quantity` included in the result.

Comment: It does work, but can I make another toString with the 4 signatures, without quantity, if somewhere else the 4 signature constructor is used?

Comment: If you have the same `toString()` signature, no.

Comment: @kocko If you need to do that just initialize quantity to "" blank string and it will print nothing if they use the other constructor.

Comment: @kocko Or initialize quantity to null in your constructor with 4 inputs and check in your toString() method if it is null print one way if not null print another way.

Comment: @kocko also you are not even using your constructors.  I showed some code on how to use your constructor.

Comment: @brso05, the OP provided his source. Obviously, he's using the default constructor and the question was why the `quantity` is not printed (which I answered). The constructor invocation you've provided doesn't guarantee that the `quantity` will be printed (the OP actually told you that the output was the same).

Comment: @kocko I meant to do OFFLINE for my comments not you sorry about that.  But actually he should be using his constructors that is why he made them.  Also if you look at my answer I told him to change his toString() method.  Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

For one you are not using either constructor you displayed in your question.  You are creating a new object then setting the fields using setters.  You may want to take a look at your setQuantity method of your class and see what it is doing.  You don't use either constructor here.

Try something like this to initialize your object:

```
StockItem item2 = new StockItem(Long.parseLong(idField.getText()), nameField.getText(), descField.getText(), (double) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText()) * 10) / 10, Integer.parseInt(quantityField.getText()));
```

It will actually use your constructor.

Also look at your toString() method of your StockItem class.  It is probably not printing quantity.  You need to add quantity field to your toString() method output.

Comment: I did use it, it gave me the same output.
This is why did not know that there is a difference in those 2.

Comment: Yes there is a difference.  The setters set individual fields while a constructor is used to intialize an entire object. Either way works using default constructor then setters or using custom constructor but the better way is using your custom constructors. That is what their there for.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you're using it isn't in the ones you're showing here. Are you sure you're able to run that without making a new constructor with no Arguments? If I'm not wrong, you should use them like this. If you want to use the **first** constructor:

```
Long id = Long.parseLong(idField.getText());
String name = nameField.getText();
String desc = descField.getText();
double price = (double) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText());

StockItem stockItemUsingFirstConstructor = new StockItem(id, name, desc, price);
```

And if you want to use the **second** constructor:

```
Long id = Long.parseLong(idField.getText());
String name = nameField.getText();
String desc = descField.getText();
double price = (double) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText());
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityField.getText());

StockItem stockItemUsingSecondConstructor = new StockItem(id, name, desc, price, quantity);
```

This is called **overloading**. :)

*P.S: Used variables to make it more clear. :)*